# Modify the tab key and enter key behavior when cellNav is used with ui-grid in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

I am using `ui-grid` with `ui-grid-selection` and `ui-grid-cellNav` modules.
I am able to navigate through the grid according to the keys behavior mentioned in [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/design/EDIT_AND_CELLNAV.md).

I want to change the behaviour of `TAB` and `ENTER` keys when using with `cellNav`.

Can someone please suggest a way to do it.

When `TAB` is pressed I want to come out of focus from the grid.
When `ENTER` is pressed I want to open hyperlink of the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behaviour of key pressing in `gridApi.cellNav.on.viewPortKeyDown` function.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        gridApi.cellNav.on.viewPortKeyDown($scope, function (event, newRowCol) {
            if (event.key == 'Tab') {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.ui-grid-cell-focus').removeClass('ui-grid-cell-focus');
            }
            if (event.key == 'enter')
                event.preventDefault();
       })
   },
   keyDownOverrides: [{
          keyCode: 13,
          ctrlKey: false
      }, //enter
      {
          keyCode: 9,
          ctrlKey: false
      } //tab
   ] 
}
```

Removing `ui-grid-cell-focus` gives only visual effect but, using arrows, you can still go to surrounding cells. If you don't want that, you can try to programmatically change focused element or prevent default action of other navigation keys.

I don't exactly undestand what do you want to do on enter press.

Comment: Thanks for the response. viewPortKeyDown() is not getting called for tab and enter keys. It is eaten up by the HandleKeyDown() I think.


Each grid row allows double click. It opens a new page. On enter press, I want the behavior same as double click.


I am not able to see keyDownOverrides in gridOptions.

Comment: KeyDownOverrides: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.cellNav.api:GridOptions .

`viewPortKeyDown()` is getting called for keys included in `KeyDownOverrides` array.

Comment: for some reason, I don't see that option in the ui_grid version I'm using. Also the ui_grid.d.ts shows viewportKeyDown() instead of capital 'P' in the name because of which it is failing at runtime.                                                        
I want to know how can we override the cellNavService's getDirection() in my controller. I have code reference (http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/13962933/Prevent+Keypress-events+(+f.e.+enter-key)) in javascript and want to know how to write it in typescript. (I am relatively new to js and ts).

Comment: The functionality of overriding cell navigation defaults is available in ui-grid release 3.1.1 and newer. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/pull/5248

Comment: I am using ui-grid 3.2.9 version. I am not able to see the KeyDownOverrides in grid options. I am coding in typescript. Am I missing something in my definition file? I don't see it in ui_grid.js file either. Can I override the getDirection() function in my typescript code somehow?